# How to retrieve value from a dictionary based on key?

Tags: python

I am stuck at this minor problem for quite some time and cannot understand why.

Let's say I have a list :

```
test = ['1', '2', '3']
```

I convert this into dictionary using

```
test_dict =  { i : test[i] for i in range(0, len(test))}

{0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3'}
```

Now when I access key based on value like this

```
print (a.get('1'))
```

it gives me None. Any suggestions in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: Try `print (test_dict[1]) #=> 2`

Comment: Dictionaries are a unidirectional mapping of keys to values.

Comment: I want to print the key not value. This would give 2 which the is the value of 1. I want to do it the other way round

Comment: What about when your dictionary is ``{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}`` (from a list of ``[1, 0, 0, 1]``)?

Answer (score 2):

Its a problem of type

```
test_dict =  { i : test[i] for i in range(0, len(test))}

{0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3'}
```

The keys will be of integer type and not string type.

Try this out instead

```
print (a.get(1))
```

Edit:
To get the keys, you can flip the dictionary creation

```
test_dict =  { test[i] : i for i in range(0, len(test))}

print (a.get(1))
0
```

Comment: It gives the value of 1. I need to get key instead like if I do test_dict[1] it should give me 0

Comment: Flip the dictionary creation around then. Check the answer I have edited it.